# Web Services programming error (Attachment support is disabled. )

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm new to Web Services, and follows a tutorial on how to set it up from my class website. However, I keep getting this warning, which causes my requests not to work. I'm somewhat at a loss, so I might need a lot of explaining on how to access certain information.

This is the warning I have been getting:

```
org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Obviously I have missing classes, but I have no idea where to download them or where to put them.

Comment: if its just a warning i suspect the warning and your requests not working are unrelated. (unless your service includes attachments)

Comment: @SlipperySeal You're entirely right. I found the problem and the program works fine now. However, I'd still like to figure out how to get rid of this warning if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following api packages: mail.jar and activation.jar
Download javamail and jaf，decompress them to get mail.jar and activation.jar.
Both of javamail and jaf can be found at java.sun.com. Reference .jars in your application.

You may also find this doc useful:

Web Services Required Jars Download Instructions:

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/ws/download_instructions_for_jars.html

Comment: this warning can be safely ignored; however, you may need them in the future if you are going to build webservice on your server. Cheers.